# dispatch_after block is not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop, dispatch-after

Please consider this simple example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"BLOCK!!!");

    });

    while (YES)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
        NSLog(@"RUN LOOP");
    }
});
}
```

The block passed into the second call (3 seconds) to `dispatch_after` is not fired. However if I don't use the first `dispatch_after` (2 seconds) then it works as expected. Why?

I know that if I remove the while loop with `NSRunLoop` running inside then it is working but I need the loop there

Comment: Is the infinite loop a good idea in that method?

Comment: @trojanfoe good idea for what? if I don't use the first dispatch_after (while still running nsrunlopp) then the second dispatch_after is fired. Why does it not fire if I add one more level of dispatch_after?

Comment: A good idea if you want stuff to work.  While you are pumping the runloop you have also interfered with the existing one.  Remove the loop and see what happens.

Comment: If I remove the loop then it's ok, sure. I know that. But I need the loop and I don't get why precisely it stops working

Comment: You probably should mention that in your question as it's obviously the culprit.

Comment: @trojanfoe done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have code which

- schedules a `dispatch_after` to run on the main queue; but then
- blocks the main queue with a `while` loop that is repeatedly calling the `NSRunLoop`.

This is just blocking the main thread from doing anything that isn’t invoked directly from the main `NSRunLoop`.

There are three solutions to this problem:

1. You can fix this by dispatching the code with the `while` loop to a global (i.e. background) queue:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad{
       [super viewDidLoad];

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           NSLog(@"OUTER");

           dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               NSLog(@"INNER!!!");
           });

           while (true) {
               [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   This technique is is a permutation of something we used to do in the pre-GCD days. This is rendered largely useless nowadays. It’s just too inefficient.
2. You can use a `NSTimer` which is scheduled and run from the `NSRunLoop`, so, while you’re still blocking the main queue, at least the timer will fire.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad{
       [super viewDidLoad];

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           NSLog(@"OUTER");

           [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 repeats:false block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
               NSLog(@"INNER!!!");
           }];

           while (true) {
               [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   This not really a solution to the problem (you’re still blocking the main thread from anything not running from the `NSRunLoop` itself), but is illuminating about the nature of the runloop.
3. Or, obviously, it’s best to just remove the `while` loop:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad{
       [super viewDidLoad];

       dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           NSLog(@"OUTER");

           dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               NSLog(@"INNER!!!");
           });
       });
   }
   ```

Bottom line, nowadays, you practically never spin on a thread (or its runloop). It’s terribly inefficient and GCD offers far more elegant ways to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: but why don't I block the main thread when I don't use the outer dispatch_after?

Comment: A [runloop](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1) processes events on a thread and `runMode:before:` allows GCD blocks/items to run, too. But GCD enforces the serial nature of its serial queues (and the main queue is a serial queue) and it won’t allow anything to run on that queue until previously dispatched blocks finish (and the `while` loop is preventing that).

Comment: Now I get it. So obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any registered input source in the sample. I don't think the dispatch counts as an input source.

In this case, `-runMode:beforeDate:` would return `NO` immediately. The infinite loop you have setup would just spin without ever exiting the current run. It never gets back to the top of the run loop and never processes any of the dispatch queues.

In [runMode:beforeDate:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop/1411525-runmode?language=objc), the behvior is defined.

> #### Discussion
>
> If no input sources or timers are attached to the run loop, this method exits immediately and returns NO; otherwise, it returns after either the first input source is processed or limitDate is reached. Manually removing all known input sources and timers from the run loop does not guarantee that the run loop will exit immediately. macOS may install and remove additional input sources as needed to process requests targeted at the receiver’s thread. Those sources could therefore prevent the run loop from exiting.

Comment: It returns YES and does not return immediately. It returns the control once the date is reached